# Seting the max width of an element with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the max width of an element.

I have a chart with an x and y axis.. i want the width of the y axis label to be a fixed with.

I've tried to set it using max width , but it doesn't seem to be working..

Any help is appreciated.

In my css I tried to set the max width of that particular class to the following:

```
.red-y-axis-labels-522 {
        max-width:20px !important;
        max-height:5px !important;
        }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkvnoj57/2/)

```css
.red-y-axis-labels-522 {
  max-width: 20px !important;
  max-height: 5px !important;
}

text {
  fill: rgb(0, 150, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<svg height="210" version="1.1" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); user-select: none; cursor: default; 
    position: relative; left: -0.6px; top: -0.2px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <desc>framework 3.3.1.sr1.19666</desc><defs>
    <linearGradient id="50290-rgba_204_204_204_1_:0-rgba_255_255_255_1_:100" x1="0" y1="1" x2="6.123233995736766e-17" y2="0" gradientTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#cccccc" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><clipPath id="D36EC035-8489-4DE3-88F9-FAE3ECE26D6E"><rect x="67" y="15" width="418" height="118" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"></rect></clipPath><linearGradient id="61390-rgba_255_230_230_1_:0-rgba_255_230_230_1_:30-rgba_255_245_245_1_:60-rgba_255_230_230_1_:90-rgba_255_230_230_1_:100" x1="0" y1="1" x2="6.123233995736766e-17" y2="0" gradientTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffe6e6" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ffe6e6" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="60%" stop-color="#fff5f5" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ffe6e6" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffe6e6" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><linearGradient id="61690-rgba_255_102_102_1_:0-rgba_255_102_102_1_:30-rgba_255_194_194_1_:60-rgba_255_102_102_1_:90-rgba_255_102_102_1_:100" x1="0" y1="1" x2="6.123233995736766e-17" y2="0" gradientTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff6666" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ff6666" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ffc2c2" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ff6666" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff6666" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient></defs><g class="red-background-483"><rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="499" height="209" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#eeeeee" stroke="#767575" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.5" style=""></rect></g><g class="red-canvas-506"><rect x="66" y="14" width="420" height="120" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#545454" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="67" y="15" width="418" height="118" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.000001" fill-opacity="1" style=""></rect></g><g class="red-axisbottom-509"><g class="red-x-axis-bands-512"></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-518"><rect x="67" y="103.5" width="418" height="14.75" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#eeeeee" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="67" y="74" width="418" height="14.75" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#eeeeee" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="67" y="44.5" width="418" height="14.75" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#eeeeee" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="67" y="14.999999999999986" width="418" height="14.75" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#eeeeee" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0.000001" style=""></rect></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-524"></g><g class="red-x-axis-lines-514"></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-520"><path fill="none" stroke="#999999" d="M67,118.5L485,118.5" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#999999" d="M67,104.5L485,104.5" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#999999" d="M67,89.5L485,89.5" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#999999" d="M67,74.5L485,74.5" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#999999" d="M67,59.5L485,59.5" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#999999" d="M67,45.5L485,45.5" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#999999" d="M67,30.5L485,30.5" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-526"></g><g class="red-x-axis-labels-516"><text x="88.16666666666667" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,-50.8333,227.1667)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="88.16666666666667">Jan</tspan></text><text x="123" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,-16,262)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="123">Feb</tspan></text><text x="157.83333333333334" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,18.8333,296.8333)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="157.83333333333334">Mar</tspan></text><text x="192.66666666666669" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,53.6667,331.6667)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="192.66666666666669">Apr</tspan></text><text x="227.5" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,88.5,366.5)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="227.5">May</tspan></text><text x="262.33333333333337" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,123.3333,401.3333)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="262.33333333333337">Jun</tspan></text><text x="297.1666666666667" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,158.1667,436.1667)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="297.1666666666667">Jul</tspan></text><text x="332" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,193,471)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="332">Aug</tspan></text><text x="366.83333333333337" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,227.8333,505.8333)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="366.83333333333337">Sep</tspan></text><text x="401.6666666666667" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,262.6667,540.6667)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="401.6666666666667">Oct</tspan></text><text x="436.5" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,297.5,575.5)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="436.5">Nov</tspan></text><text x="471.33333333333337" y="139" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,332.3333,610.3333)"><tspan dy="-3.296875" x="471.33333333333337">Dec</tspan></text></g>
    <g class="red-y-axis-labels-522"><text x="63" y="133" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" 
    style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px"
    transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
    <tspan dy="4.390625" x="63">0</tspan></text><text x="63" y="103.5" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><tspan dy="4.390625" x="63">3.25M</tspan></text><text x="63" y="74" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><tspan dy="4.390625" x="63">6.5M</tspan></text><text x="63" y="29.749999999999986" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><tspan dy="4.390624999999986" x="63">11.375M</tspan></text></g><g class="red-y-axis-labels-528"></g><g class="red-axis-name-529"></g></g><g class="red-dataset-484"><g class="red-columns-557" clip-path="url('https://localhost:44321/app_Member/sustainPlant.aspx?companyName=Chicago&amp;theYear=2016&amp;zone=AZ#D36EC035-8489-4DE3-88F9-FAE3ECE26D6E')" style=""><rect x="70.5" y="29.5" width="14" height="104" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="105.5" y="30.5" width="14" height="103" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="140.5" y="39.5" width="14" height="94" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="174.5" y="58.5" width="14" height="75" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="209.5" y="62.5" width="14" height="71" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="244.5" y="71.5" width="14" height="62" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="279.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="314.5" y="65.5" width="14" height="68" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="349.5" y="74.5" width="14" height="59" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="383.5" y="59.5" width="14" height="74" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="418.5" y="57.5" width="14" height="76" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="453.5" y="47.5" width="14" height="86" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffe6e6" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="84.5" y="79.5" width="14" height="54" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="119.5" y="85.5" width="14" height="48" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="154.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="188.5" y="54.5" width="14" height="79" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="223.5" y="68.5" width="14" height="65" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="258.5" y="63.5" width="14" height="70" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="293.5" y="73.5" width="14" height="60" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="328.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="363.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="397.5" y="50.5" width="14" height="83" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="432.5" y="56.5" width="14" height="77" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect><rect x="467.5" y="17.5" width="14" height="116" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff6666" stroke="#333333" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,4" stroke-linejoin="miter" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;"></rect></g></g><g class="red-axistop-510"><g class="red-x-axis-bands-511"></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-517"></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-523"></g><g class="red-x-axis-lines-513"></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-519"></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-525"></g><g class="red-x-axis-labels-515"></g><g class="red-y-axis-labels-521"></g><g class="red-y-axis-labels-527"></g></g><g class="red-datalabels-505" style=""></g><g class="red-legend-606" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,191.5,169.5)"><rect x="0" y="0" width="170" height="26" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#404040" stroke-opacity="0.05" stroke-width="5" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linecap="round" shape-rendering="default" style="stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;"></rect><rect x="0" y="0" width="170" height="26" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#404040" stroke-opacity="0.1" stroke-width="3" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linecap="round" shape-rendering="default" style="stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;"></rect><rect x="0" y="0" width="170" height="26" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#404040" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linecap="round" shape-rendering="default" style="stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;"></rect><rect x="0" y="0" width="170" height="26" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#545454" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" style=""></rect><rect x="4" y="4" width="81" height="18" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="none" fill-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" style="cursor: pointer;"></rect><text x="24" y="5.5" text-anchor="start" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: start; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px"><tspan dy="12.078125" x="24">2015 GHG</tspan></text><path fill="url('https://localhost:44321/app_Member/sustainPlant.aspx?companyName=Chicago&amp;theYear=2016&amp;zone=AZ#61390-rgba_255_230_230_1_:0-rgba_255_230_230_1_:30-rgba_255_245_245_1_:60-rgba_255_230_230_1_:90-rgba_255_230_230_1_:100')" stroke="#998a8a" d="M7,19L7,10.600000000000001L10,10.600000000000001L10,19ZM11.5,19L11.5,7L14.5,7L14.5,19ZM16,19L16,14.2L19,14.2L19,19Z" stroke-width="0.5" opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;"></path><rect x="85" y="4" width="81" height="18" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="none" fill-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" style="cursor: pointer;"></rect><text x="105" y="5.5" text-anchor="start" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: start; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px"><tspan dy="12.078125" x="105">2016 GHG</tspan></text><path fill="url('https://localhost:44321/app_Member/sustainPlant.aspx?companyName=Chicago&amp;theYear=2016&amp;zone=AZ#61690-rgba_255_102_102_1_:0-rgba_255_102_102_1_:30-rgba_255_194_194_1_:60-rgba_255_102_102_1_:90-rgba_255_102_102_1_:100')" stroke="#993d3d" d="M88,19L88,10.600000000000001L91,10.600000000000001L91,19ZM92.5,19L92.5,7L95.5,7L95.5,19ZM97,19L97,14.2L100,14.2L100,19Z" stroke-width="0.5" opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;"></path></g><g class="red-hot-485"><rect x="70.5" y="29.5" width="14" height="104" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="105.5" y="30.5" width="14" height="103" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="140.5" y="39.5" width="14" height="94" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="174.5" y="58.5" width="14" height="75" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="209.5" y="62.5" width="14" height="71" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="244.5" y="71.5" width="14" height="62" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="279.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="314.5" y="65.5" width="14" height="68" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="349.5" y="74.5" width="14" height="59" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="383.5" y="59.5" width="14" height="74" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="418.5" y="57.5" width="14" height="76" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="453.5" y="47.5" width="14" height="86" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="84.5" y="79.5" width="14" height="54" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="119.5" y="85.5" width="14" height="48" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="154.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="188.5" y="54.5" width="14" height="79" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="223.5" y="68.5" width="14" height="65" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="258.5" y="63.5" width="14" height="70" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="293.5" y="73.5" width="14" height="60" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="328.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="363.5" y="70.5" width="14" height="63" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="397.5" y="50.5" width="14" height="83" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="432.5" y="56.5" width="14" height="77" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect><rect x="467.5" y="17.5" width="14" height="116" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.000001" style=""></rect></g><g class="red-buttons-487"><g class="red-button-501" style=""><rect x="472.5" y="6.5" width="18" height="17" r="0" rx="2" ry="2" fill="url('https://localhost:44321/app_Member/sustainPlant.aspx?companyName=Chicago&amp;theYear=2016&amp;zone=AZ#50290-rgba_204_204_204_1_:0-rgba_255_255_255_1_:100')" stroke="#bbbbbb" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" style="opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1;"></rect><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#9a9a9a" d="M476.5,17.5L476.5,20.5L487.5,20.5L487.5,17.5L487.5,20.5L476.5,20.5ZM481.5,19.5L478.5,15L480.5,15L480.5,9.5L482.5,9.5L482.5,15L484.5,15Z" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" style=""></path><rect x="472.5" y="6.5" width="18" height="17" r="0" rx="2" ry="2" fill="#c0c0c0" stroke="#c0c0c0" fill-opacity="0.000001" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke-width="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </rect></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: The class .red-y-axis-bands-522 doesn't exist in your HTML, I don't know what part of your chart are you trying to modify...

Comment: I am sorry.. it should be the class 'red-y-axis-labels-522'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set max width on `<g>` element, this element cannot be styled via css.

As workaround you could use `<foreignObejct>` apply your width and add inside another svg object with the labels.

This you would have to use instead of whole `<g>`

```
<foreignObject width="150" height="150" class="red-y-axis-labels-522">
    <svg>
        <text x="63" y="133" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" 
    style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px"
    transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"  height="2">
            <tspan dy="4.390625" x="63" >0</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="63" y="103.5" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <tspan dy="4.390625" x="63">3.25M</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="63" y="74" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <tspan dy="4.390625" x="63">6.5M</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="63" y="29.749999999999986" text-anchor="end" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <tspan dy="4.390624999999986" x="63">11.375M</tspan>
        </text>
    </svg>
</foreignObject>
```

I do not know what are you trying exactly to achieve but here you could modify width of the labels. For the height you were trying to set height 5px on the whole labels block which would render it invisible.

With this code you can set width as you need but keep in mind that all text elements nested in the svg have its own coordinates so you would have to position them properly to achieve what you want.

That being said I think that what are you trying to do with CSS should be rather done by javascript lybrary such as svg.js or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of an element

```
.red-y-axis-bands-522 {
width: 20px
}
```

Or the maximum width

```
.red-y-axis-bands-522 {
max-width: 20px
}
```

If this doesn't work then maybe the content inside this element is spilling outside of the element. However we'd need to see more code than what you have provided in order to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: this is what I've done in my code. but it didn't work. JSFiddle has the full code in it.